# Delegate event handler from Excel in IronPython not working

Tags: python, .net, excel, ironpython

I am doing a small development within Rhinoceros (a CAD program) through an IronPython interface inside the program itself. One of the main elements of the code is to manage that Rhinoceros is able to update a geometry whenever a parameter is changed in an associated Excel document. So far I have managed to run a separate event listening loop, however I am not able to register any events from Excel.

```
class ExcelGUI():
    def __init__(self):
        # Generate the excel Workbook and assign the sheet. In the future, a template can be used.
        self.xlApp = excelApp()
        self.taskInterpreter = TaskInterpreter(self.xlApp.sheet,"B1")

        # Generate the update handler
        self.updateEvent=threading.Event()
        self.xlApp.sheet.Change += self.triggerEvent

        # Run the listen for event loop with the following refresh rate.

        self.main_loop=EventLoop(self.updateEvent, self.run_task)
        self.main_loop.start()
        print("Loop Started")
        
    def run_task(self):
        task=self.taskInterpreter.readTask()
        return task()

    def triggerEvent(self):
        self.updateEvent.set()

class EventLoop(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, Event, Func):
        super(EventLoop,self).__init__()
        self.func=Func
        self.event=Event
    def run(self):
        keepOpen=True
        while keepOpen:
            print("Waiting for Event")
            self.event.wait()
            print("Event Detected")
            keepOpen=self.func()
            self.event.clear()

if __name__=="__main__":
    ExcelGUI()
    print("Code Finished")
```

It looks like the main thread of code runs through the program and exits while the other thread is still waiting to trigger. I have tested within debug mode and it seems like the handler doesn't fire but I also don't have a way to test this hypothesis.
Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you in advance. :)